# [...]と言われ、傷つく母親たち - Was the に left out here or is it something else?

Tags: grammar, particle-に, passive-voice

For full context:
https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/web_tokushu/2018_1130.html?utm_int=news_contents_tokushu_002

The following sentence:
死産や流産のあと「早く忘れた方がいい」「次の子どもを」と言われ、傷つく母親たち。

My attempt at translation:
"After a stillbirth or miscarriage, it is said by wounded parents 'It's better to quickly forget' or '[think about] the next baby'".

What irritates me is the lack of the に particle in と言われ　傷つく母親たち. 
Id expect it to be と言われ 傷つく母親たちに。

I could also imagine it being translated as "After a miscarriage or stillbirth, there are wounded parents by whom it is said '...'..."

But I also must admit that Im a bit confused by the conjunctive form 言われ. There is no second verb which would make it necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The entirety of 死産や流産のあと「早く忘れた方がいい」「次の子どもを」と言われ、傷つく modifies 母親たち。言われ is the 連用形 of 言われる, and connects to 傷つく. (Semantically 言われ、傷つく = 言われて、傷つく)

Therefore the sentence means "mothers who are hurt by others telling them that they should quickly forget, or hope for another child, after a stillbirth or miscarriage."